# maven install error,can't perform any maven operation on specifical maven project/modules

Tags: maven, installation

all! i need some help on what happened to my eclipse maven plugin .
the building process worked well yestoday! while  it failed to build this morning ! 
i have googled but still not able to locate what happened !
i got the stack trace from the error log ; could somebody offer me some clue for this error,or  what does 16386 mean there  if possible
thanks in advance!

stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16386
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2470)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1257)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1105)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3DomBuilder.build(Xpp3DomBuilder.java:179)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3DomBuilder.build(Xpp3DomBuilder.java:86)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

16386 is the index in the array. 
The problem is that the array is not as big as 16386. (i.e. size of the array < 16387)

Anyway, it won't help you to solve this problem.

You can check that your pom.xml contains this (and that it is valid):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

**EDIT**

Your problem is certainly a local problem. So first check the validity of your maven config files:

- .m2/settings.xml
- M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml

If these look fine, then the problem may also be caused by a "corrupt" (bad XML) pom.xml ANYWHERE in your local repo... the easiest workaround is to just wipe your ~/.m2/repository, to let Maven re-download everything.

Comment: thanks then,16386 would be  a  meaningless number; i check the pom file there is nothing strange！ what's weird is my collegue download the same project and able to import the project！ then same like it‘s may not be the pom problem！

Comment: I solved this by remove all the dependency ，and added back piece by piece！ and found the problem lie in a dependency of my local respositry .accepted ur answer here cause it offers some general solutions that  might help others.  thanks

Answer (score 22):

I wiped my `~/.m2/` folder and then re-ran and Maven re-downloaded everything - worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem (even `mvn clean -U` failed), it usually started when I added a new dependency to my `pom.xml` file.

The weird thing is that commenting out the dependency will not solve the problem, only removing it (with any comments related to it) will solve the problem.

Note: I was using fixed versions for various Maven plugins via "lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom)". Like this:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    ...
  </build>
```

This worked fine except for some dependencies.
The only solution to include these dependencies was to remove the fixed versions from pluginManagement. I suppose it is possible to find out the right version  to use for reach plugin but that seems difficult (any advice on this ?).

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_265, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-112-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

mvn clean
...
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8294 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8294
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8294
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parsePI (MXParser.java:2502)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl (MXParser.java:1283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next (MXParser.java:1131)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextTag (MXParser.java:1116) ...
```

Similar issues:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6286 (v3.5.0, but I use 3.6.0 and it is still broken)
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2499
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53060 "This looks like https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-utils/issues/22 - which suggests that the maven integration plugin isn't using the specified maven installation, but is instead using some specific out-of-date version of plexus-utils."

Similar SO issues:

- [maven is throwing ArrayOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559325/maven-is-throwing-arrayoutofboundsexception)

Answer (score 0):

in my case, a newly added dependency was causing this(`jsonPath`) - i removed it and achieved the same requirement with `jsons-simple` then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, after installing a newer version of `mvn` it worked.

previous version => `3.3.9`
new version => `3.8.6`