# Maven Error 9723

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to java and maven, below is the build output of maven in Eclipse, please help.

> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Building DudyScheduleManager 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 0.919 s
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-18T18:59:57+08:00
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   **[ERROR] 9723**
>   ****[ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.****

Comment: Try rerunning your build with `-X` key and post the stacktrace you get

Comment: Maven doesn't really use error codes, it use to have more descriptive error messages. So I guess no one can tell what is wrong with your project, from this limited information.

Comment: @Roman

Rerun with -X parameter, ouput:
[ERROR] 9723
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9723
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2502)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseEpilog(MXParser.java:1604)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1434)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1131)

Comment: Are you able to post the pom.xml?

Comment: Please post your whole pom file....furthermore check to run Maven only on plain command line to see if this issue is related other thing...which version of Maven do you use?

Comment: could be https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-utils/issues/22

Comment: I am using maven version 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

This indicates a "corrupted" XML file somewhere in your local Maven repository, and as suggested on https://stackoverflow.com/a/43637902/421602, the simplest solution when you hit this is to just wipe your ~/.m2/repository folder.

.