# Build failure [error] 15669

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, maven-3

I have a test project for a web site and I'm using maven. When I'm running maven test in Eclipse it works fine but it fails when I launch "maven test" command line.

Here is the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <!-- Project description -->
    <name>Selenium Name</name>
    <groupId>com.school.selenium.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-name</artifactId>
    <description>Automatisation Selenium du portail</description>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- PROPERTIES IMPORT -->
    <properties>
        <!-- Libraries versions -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <selenium_version>3.4.0</selenium_version>
        <xml_beans_version>2.6.0</xml_beans_version>
        <poi_version>3.9</poi_version>
        <junit_version>3.9</junit_version>
    </properties>

    <!-- LIBRARIES IMPORT -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${selenium_version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>${xml_beans_version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi_version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <!-- BUILD CONFIGURATION -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- BUILD SETUP -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>_01_Authentification_NF_Test.java</include>
                        <include>_01_Authentification_Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.20</version> <configuration> <includes> <include>_01_Authentification.java</include> 
                </includes> </configuration> </plugin>SURFIRE PLUGIN -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showSuccess>true</showSuccess>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

And here is the output of the command line "maven -e test"

OUTPUT

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Selenium InBlue 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.714 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-18T10:47:32+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 15669
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15669
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2502)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseEpilog(MXParser.java:1604)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1434)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1131)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:3856)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:595)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProcessor.read(DefaultModelProcessor.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1097)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:829)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:331)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:321)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:325)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I checked the Path, it seems good and it worked in Eclipse. Also I'm using packages in my Java project (one for New Features and another one for Non-regression). I'm working on Windows 10.

Comment: Can you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17917261/4121573)? If it doesn't help, can you run `mvn test -X` (debug mode), and post the output? Last thing, does it fail as well if you run another command such as `mvn install`?

Comment: I checked the link but I don't have any setting.xml file in my .m2 directory. And mvn install fails too.

Comment: You should have a `settings.xml` in the config folder of your mvn installation folder, worth giving a check there too. (from the debug output I'd guess here: `C:\Users\username\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..\conf\settings.xml`)

Comment: Indeed I have it. All is comment except this: `<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">`

Comment: Ok, just to definitely eliminate any possible issue with settings, can you post the output of `mvn help:effective-settings`?

Comment: the output of `mvn help:effective-settings` is in the answer below. I had to post it in an answer due to the length of the output.

Comment: Have you tried wiping out your `~/.m2` (Local Maven repository) and then having your project re-download everything ? One of the reasons that is cited in the link that @asettouf shared suggests that this can happen due to a corrupted local repository.

Comment: It worked ! I had to remove all files related to maven, re-download the maven-bin directory and re-setup the path. Just wiping out the `~/.m2` repository wasn't enough. Thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

"mvn install" "mvn verify" fail too. "mvn clean" "mvn selenium:start-server" worked

OUTPUT

```
mvn -X test

    Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T21:39:06+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\username\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Users\username\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\username\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from C:\Users\username\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\username\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\username\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\username\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.school.selenium.project:selenium-project:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.school.selenium.project:selenium-project:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [test]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Selenium project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       com.school.selenium.project:selenium-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile, test]
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <buildFilters default-value="${project.build.filters}"/>
  <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</encoding>
  <escapeString>${maven.resources.escapeString}</escapeString>
  <escapeWindowsPaths default-value="true">${maven.resources.escapeWindowsPaths}</escapeWindowsPaths>
  <includeEmptyDirs default-value="false">${maven.resources.includeEmptyDirs}</includeEmptyDirs>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <overwrite default-value="false">${maven.resources.overwrite}</overwrite>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <resources default-value="${project.resources}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <supportMultiLineFiltering default-value="false">${maven.resources.supportMultiLineFiltering}</supportMultiLineFiltering>
  <useBuildFilters default-value="true"/>
  <useDefaultDelimiters default-value="true"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <buildDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <classpathElements default-value="${project.compileClasspathElements}"/>
  <compileSourceRoots default-value="${project.compileSourceRoots}"/>
  <compilerId default-value="javac">${maven.compiler.compilerId}</compilerId>
  <compilerReuseStrategy default-value="${reuseCreated}">${maven.compiler.compilerReuseStrategy}</compilerReuseStrategy>
  <compilerVersion>${maven.compiler.compilerVersion}</compilerVersion>
  <debug default-value="true">${maven.compiler.debug}</debug>
  <debuglevel>${maven.compiler.debuglevel}</debuglevel>
  <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</encoding>
  <executable>${maven.compiler.executable}</executable>
  <failOnError default-value="true">${maven.compiler.failOnError}</failOnError>
  <forceJavacCompilerUse default-value="false">${maven.compiler.forceJavacCompilerUse}</forceJavacCompilerUse>
  <fork default-value="false">${maven.compiler.fork}</fork>
  <generatedSourcesDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations"/>
  <maxmem>${maven.compiler.maxmem}</maxmem>
  <meminitial>${maven.compiler.meminitial}</meminitial>
  <mojoExecution>${mojoExecution}</mojoExecution>
  <optimize default-value="false">${maven.compiler.optimize}</optimize>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <projectArtifact default-value="${project.artifact}"/>
  <showDeprecation default-value="false">${maven.compiler.showDeprecation}</showDeprecation>
  <showWarnings default-value="false">${maven.compiler.showWarnings}</showWarnings>
  <skipMultiThreadWarning default-value="false">${maven.compiler.skipMultiThreadWarning}</skipMultiThreadWarning>
  <source default-value="1.5">1.8</source>
  <staleMillis default-value="0">${lastModGranularityMs}</staleMillis>
  <target default-value="1.5">1.8</target>
  <verbose default-value="false">${maven.compiler.verbose}</verbose>
  <mavenSession default-value="${session}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <buildFilters default-value="${project.build.filters}"/>
  <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</encoding>
  <escapeString>${maven.resources.escapeString}</escapeString>
  <escapeWindowsPaths default-value="true">${maven.resources.escapeWindowsPaths}</escapeWindowsPaths>
  <includeEmptyDirs default-value="false">${maven.resources.includeEmptyDirs}</includeEmptyDirs>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
  <overwrite default-value="false">${maven.resources.overwrite}</overwrite>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <resources default-value="${project.testResources}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
  <supportMultiLineFiltering default-value="false">${maven.resources.supportMultiLineFiltering}</supportMultiLineFiltering>
  <useBuildFilters default-value="true"/>
  <useDefaultDelimiters default-value="true"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <buildDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <classpathElements default-value="${project.testClasspathElements}"/>
  <compileSourceRoots default-value="${project.testCompileSourceRoots}"/>
  <compilerId default-value="javac">${maven.compiler.compilerId}</compilerId>
  <compilerReuseStrategy default-value="${reuseCreated}">${maven.compiler.compilerReuseStrategy}</compilerReuseStrategy>
  <compilerVersion>${maven.compiler.compilerVersion}</compilerVersion>
  <debug default-value="true">${maven.compiler.debug}</debug>
  <debuglevel>${maven.compiler.debuglevel}</debuglevel>
  <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</encoding>
  <executable>${maven.compiler.executable}</executable>
  <failOnError default-value="true">${maven.compiler.failOnError}</failOnError>
  <forceJavacCompilerUse default-value="false">${maven.compiler.forceJavacCompilerUse}</forceJavacCompilerUse>
  <fork default-value="false">${maven.compiler.fork}</fork>
  <generatedTestSourcesDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/test-annotations"/>
  <maxmem>${maven.compiler.maxmem}</maxmem>
  <meminitial>${maven.compiler.meminitial}</meminitial>
  <mojoExecution>${mojoExecution}</mojoExecution>
  <optimize default-value="false">${maven.compiler.optimize}</optimize>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
  <showDeprecation default-value="false">${maven.compiler.showDeprecation}</showDeprecation>
  <showWarnings default-value="false">${maven.compiler.showWarnings}</showWarnings>
  <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
  <skipMultiThreadWarning default-value="false">${maven.compiler.skipMultiThreadWarning}</skipMultiThreadWarning>
  <source default-value="1.5">1.8</source>
  <staleMillis default-value="0">${lastModGranularityMs}</staleMillis>
  <target default-value="1.5">1.8</target>
  <testSource>${maven.compiler.testSource}</testSource>
  <testTarget>${maven.compiler.testTarget}</testTarget>
  <verbose default-value="false">${maven.compiler.verbose}</verbose>
  <mavenSession default-value="${session}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <additionalClasspathElements>${maven.test.additionalClasspath}</additionalClasspathElements>
  <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <childDelegation default-value="false">${childDelegation}</childDelegation>
  <classesDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <classpathDependencyExcludes>${maven.test.dependency.excludes}</classpathDependencyExcludes>
  <debugForkedProcess>${maven.surefire.debug}</debugForkedProcess>
  <dependenciesToScan>${dependenciesToScan}</dependenciesToScan>
  <disableXmlReport default-value="false">${disableXmlReport}</disableXmlReport>
  <enableAssertions default-value="true">${enableAssertions}</enableAssertions>
  <excludedGroups>${excludedGroups}</excludedGroups>
  <excludesFile>${surefire.excludesFile}</excludesFile>
  <failIfNoSpecifiedTests>${surefire.failIfNoSpecifiedTests}</failIfNoSpecifiedTests>
  <failIfNoTests>${failIfNoTests}</failIfNoTests>
  <forkCount default-value="1">${forkCount}</forkCount>
  <forkMode default-value="once">${forkMode}</forkMode>
  <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds default-value="30">${surefire.exitTimeout}</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
  <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>${surefire.timeout}</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
  <groups>${groups}</groups>
  <includes>
    <include>_01_Authentification_NF_Test.java</include>
    <include>_01_Authentification_Test.java</include>
  </includes>
  <includesFile>${surefire.includesFile}</includesFile>
  <junitArtifactName default-value="junit:junit">${junitArtifactName}</junitArtifactName>
  <jvm>${jvm}</jvm>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <objectFactory>${objectFactory}</objectFactory>
  <parallel>${parallel}</parallel>
  <parallelMavenExecution default-value="${session.parallel}"/>
  <parallelOptimized default-value="true">${parallelOptimized}</parallelOptimized>
  <parallelTestsTimeoutForcedInSeconds>${surefire.parallel.forcedTimeout}</parallelTestsTimeoutForcedInSeconds>
  <parallelTestsTimeoutInSeconds>${surefire.parallel.timeout}</parallelTestsTimeoutInSeconds>
  <perCoreThreadCount default-value="true">${perCoreThreadCount}</perCoreThreadCount>
  <pluginArtifactMap>${plugin.artifactMap}</pluginArtifactMap>
  <pluginDescriptor default-value="${plugin}"/>
  <printSummary default-value="true">${surefire.printSummary}</printSummary>
  <projectArtifactMap>${project.artifactMap}</projectArtifactMap>
  <projectBuildDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <redirectTestOutputToFile default-value="false">${maven.test.redirectTestOutputToFile}</redirectTestOutputToFile>
  <remoteRepositories default-value="${project.pluginArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <reportFormat default-value="brief">${surefire.reportFormat}</reportFormat>
  <reportNameSuffix default-value="">${surefire.reportNameSuffix}</reportNameSuffix>
  <reportsDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports"/>
  <rerunFailingTestsCount default-value="0">${surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount}</rerunFailingTestsCount>
  <reuseForks default-value="true">${reuseForks}</reuseForks>
  <runOrder default-value="filesystem">${surefire.runOrder}</runOrder>
  <shutdown default-value="testset">${surefire.shutdown}</shutdown>
  <skip default-value="false">${maven.test.skip}</skip>
  <skipAfterFailureCount default-value="0">${surefire.skipAfterFailureCount}</skipAfterFailureCount>
  <skipExec>${maven.test.skip.exec}</skipExec>
  <skipTests default-value="false">${skipTests}</skipTests>
  <suiteXmlFiles>${surefire.suiteXmlFiles}</suiteXmlFiles>
  <tempDir default-value="surefire">${tempDir}</tempDir>
  <test>${test}</test>
  <testClassesDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
  <testFailureIgnore default-value="false">${maven.test.failure.ignore}</testFailureIgnore>
  <testNGArtifactName default-value="org.testng:testng">${testNGArtifactName}</testNGArtifactName>
  <testSourceDirectory default-value="${project.build.testSourceDirectory}"/>
  <threadCount>${threadCount}</threadCount>
  <threadCountClasses default-value="0">${threadCountClasses}</threadCountClasses>
  <threadCountMethods default-value="0">${threadCountMethods}</threadCountMethods>
  <threadCountSuites default-value="0">${threadCountSuites}</threadCountSuites>
  <trimStackTrace default-value="true">${trimStackTrace}</trimStackTrace>
  <useFile default-value="true">${surefire.useFile}</useFile>
  <useManifestOnlyJar default-value="true">${surefire.useManifestOnlyJar}</useManifestOnlyJar>
  <useSystemClassLoader default-value="true">${surefire.useSystemClassLoader}</useSystemClassLoader>
  <useUnlimitedThreads default-value="false">${useUnlimitedThreads}</useUnlimitedThreads>
  <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] --- init fork of com.school.selenium.project:selenium-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.6:report-only (default) ---
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []
[DEBUG] --- exit fork of com.school.selenium.project:selenium-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.6:report-only (default) ---
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.6:report-only (default)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <aggregate default-value="false">${aggregate}</aggregate>
  <linkXRef default-value="true">${linkXRef}</linkXRef>
  <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
  <outputName default-value="surefire-report">${outputName}</outputName>
  <project>${project}</project>
  <reactorProjects>${reactorProjects}</reactorProjects>
  <showSuccess default-value="true">${showSuccess}</showSuccess>
  <xrefLocation default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/xref-test"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.684 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-18T11:39:37+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 15669
[ERROR]
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45162269/edit) your post instead of posting an answer to avoid confusions.

Comment: I wasn't able to do so because it was to long

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn help:effective-settings
```

OUTPUT

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (493 B at
 951 B/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/2.2/maven-help-plugin-2.2.p
om
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/2.2/maven-help-plugin-2.2.po
m (8.7 kB at 126 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/2.2/maven-help-plugin-2.2.j
ar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/2.2/maven-help-plugin-2.2.ja
r (68 kB at 534 kB/s)
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Selenium school 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:effective-settings (default-cli) @ selenium-school ---
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-a
pi-2.2.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-ap
i-2.2.1.pom (1.9 kB at 22 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting/2.2.1/maven-reporting-2.2.1
.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting/2.2.1/maven-reporting-2.2.1.
pom (1.4 kB at 12 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.pom (2.0 k
B at 16 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.1/doxia-1.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.1/doxia-1.1.pom (15 kB at 167 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.pom

Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.pom
(1.6 kB at 23 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.pom (8.0 kB at 131 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/2.4.3/maven-plugi
n-tools-api-2.4.3.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/2.4.3/maven-plugin
-tools-api-2.4.3.pom (4.6 kB at 58 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools/2.4.3/maven-plugin-to
ols-2.4.3.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools/2.4.3/maven-plugin-too
ls-2.4.3.pom (9.9 kB at 153 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.6/plexus-utils-1.5.6.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.6/plexus-utils-1.5.6.pom (5.3 kB a
t 78 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/1.0.12/plexus-1.0.12.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/1.0.12/plexus-1.0.12.pom (9.8 kB at 124 kB/s
)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev/jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev/jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.pom (1.3 kB at 13 kB/s)

Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-contai
ner-default-1.0-alpha-7.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-contain
er-default-1.0-alpha-7.pom (1.3 kB at 21 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-containers/1.0.2/plexus-containers-1.0.2.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-containers/1.0.2/plexus-containers-1.0.2.pom (471 B at 6.
5 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-root/1.0.3/plexus-root-1.0.3.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/plexus/plexus-root/1.0.3/plexus-root-1.0.3.pom (6.0 kB at 109 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.7/plexus-utils-1.5.7.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.7/plexus-utils-1.5.7.pom (8.1 kB a
t 117 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.pom (1.2 kB at 17 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.3/xstream-1.4.3.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.3/xstream-1.4.3.pom (8.6 kB at 121
 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream-parent/1.4.3/xstream-parent-1.4.3.pom

Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream-parent/1.4.3/xstream-parent-1.4.3.pom
(19 kB at 290 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/codehaus-parent/3/codehaus-parent-3.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/codehaus-parent/3/codehaus-parent-3.pom (4.1 kB at 60 kB/s
)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.pom (386 B at 4.5 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.pom (1.6 kB at 15 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-a
pi-2.2.1.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.jar

Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/2.4.3/maven-plugi
n-tools-api-2.4.3.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-ap
i-2.2.1.jar (9.8 kB at 134 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev/jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.jar (13 kB
 at 90 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-contai
ner-default-1.0-alpha-9.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.jar
(11 kB at 73 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.7/plexus-utils-1.5.7.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar (41 kB at 231 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/2.4.3/maven-plugin
-tools-api-2.4.3.jar (51 kB at 277 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.3/xstream-1.4.3.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev/jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar (138 kB at 549 kB/s
)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-contain
er-default-1.0-alpha-9.jar (195 kB at 530 kB/s)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar (7.2 kB at 19 kB/s)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar (153 kB at 395 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.7/plexus-utils-1.5.7.jar (266 kB a
t 568 kB/s)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.3/xstream-1.4.3.jar (482 kB at 995
 kB/s)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar (25 kB at 50 kB/s)
[INFO]
Effective user-specific configuration settings:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated by Maven Help Plugin on 2017-07-18T12:44:12                  -->
<!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/                -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective Settings for 'username' on 'hostname'                       -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLoca
tion="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  <localRepository xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">C:\Users\username\.m2\repository</localRepository>
  <pluginGroups xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">
    <pluginGroup>org.apache.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
    <pluginGroup>org.codehaus.mojo</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.443 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-18T12:44:12+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/167M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```